# Mass Assignment issue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was going through this article below. 
[http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2:-adding-comments](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2%3a-adding-comments)

Below is the code where we create a new `Comment` object and `associate` with corresponding `article`.

```
@comment = Comment.new
@comment.article_id = @article.id
```

Can anyone explain me what the author is trying to say below. Can anyone show me how to do otherwise without the security thing for better understanding.

> Due to the Rails’ mass-assignment protection, the `article_id`
>   attribute of the new `Comment` object needs to be manually assigned
>   with the `id` of the `Article`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you were reading was referring to rails 3. Rails 3 doesn't use strong parameters like Rails 4 and instead uses `attr_accessible` with a list of attributes which are permitted to be mass assigned.

Mass assignment in ruby is everything where you use a hash to set multiple variables at once in methods like `new`, `create` or `assign_attributes`. Quite often it is not a good idea to allow mass assignment of foreign keys.

In summary, author meant that those two lines cannot be written as:

```
@comment = Comment.new(article_id: @article.id)
```

since `article_id` is not listed in `attr_accessible` and it will raise Mass Assignment security exception.