# How does form_for generate paths in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can anyone explain me on how the `paths` are generated using `form_for`?. The below code generates a path article_comments_path.

```
<%= form_for [@article, @comment] do |f| %>    
<% end %>
```

I mean how does it exactly generate `article_comments_path` and not `articles_comment_path`

Comment: You're passing it a single article and comment in an array. Types are used as a way of determining what to do.

Comment: How do you say, I am passing a single article. <%= form_for(@article) %> generates /articles then /article right.

Comment: Yes, because you're no longer passing an array, you're passing an object of a specific class.

Comment: How does this whole magic works or gets generated, any associated article on this to get in deeper.

Comment: @Shane - There are no better articles than a source code itself. Also reading it is probably the best way to learn rails really deeply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is using `polymorphic_path` method to determine the path. It is basicaly a wrpaper around `polymorphic_url`: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url

Update:

`polymorphic_path` is using internally method called `build_named_route_call`. When it gets an array, it pull the last record out of the array (with `pop`) and then iterates over the remaining array, changing all the objects to

1. if it is a model it takes it class and calls `model_name.singular_route_key'
2. if it is a symbol or string, leaves it as it is

Then we are left with the last element. It can be singular or plural, this is resolved in `polymorphic_url` method with this case statement:

```
inflection = if options[:action] && options[:action].to_s == "new"
      args.pop
      :singular
    elsif (record.respond_to?(:persisted?) && !record.persisted?)
      args.pop
      :plural
    elsif record.is_a?(Class)
      args.pop
      :plural
    else
      :singular
    end
```

where record is a first element of the array (if array is passed). `inlection` var is then passed to `build_named_route_call` so it can build correct helper name. As you can see this form will generate different paths depending on whether the first element is already persisted or not.

Comment: I mean how does it exactly generate article_comments_path and not articles_comment_path

Comment: Thanks, can you help me out in this question too if possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930854/mass-assignment-issue-in-rails?noredirect=1#comment36857142_23930854